# No keyboard in Xorg

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using Arch Linux (installed from a Live CD) and I am having trouble with the keyboard in Xorg. I am mostly sure it's a matter of configuration, I'm attaching my `10-keyboard.conf` file:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "system-keyboard"
Driver "kbd"
MatchIsKeyboard "on"
Option "XkbRules" "xorg"
Option "XkbLayout" "gb"
Option "XkbModel" "pc104"
Option "XkbVariant" "latin"
EndSection
```

I need to have the GB layout every time I reboot my computer, but I don't know if I am missing something. I also don't know if I have to use pc104 or pc105, I have a ThinkPad T400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am mostly sure it's a matter of configuration, I'm attaching my 10-keyboard.conf file:

Modern `Xorg` does not require much configuring, and it is recommended to run without a configuration as the configuration language is very intricate and error-prone. Instead, try running `setxkbmap gb` once the X server has launched to see if the keyboard can be configured that way. If that works, place the command in your `.xinitrc` so that it is executed automatically every time you start the X server.